# Firebase auth Phone number with React(Nextjs)

Tags: firebase, authentication, next.js, recaptcha

from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth to re-render the recaptcha

```
grecaptcha.reset(window.recaptchaWidgetId);

// Or, if you haven't stored the widget ID:
window.recaptchaVerifier.render().then(function(widgetId) {
  grecaptcha.reset(widgetId);
}``


I'm wondering where I can find   " grecaptcha "
```